# Saying the contract static checker that a extension method not allow null?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

```
 Contract.Requires(completeURL.IsUri()); // Error: Contract.Requires(completeURL != null)
```

Can I do this without Contract.Assume()?
I mean something like this:

```
    [Pure]
    [DefinitelyNotANullStringAfterThatMethod]
    public static bool IsUri(this string str)
    {
        return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(str, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but you might try `Contract.Ensures(!Contract.Result<bool>() || str != null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [Pure]
    public static bool IsUri(this string str)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(!Contract.Result<bool>() || str != null); // by Dan Bryant
        return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(str, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
```

Maybe?

Comment: `Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));`

Comment: I don't believe this will ensure that condition at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, having contracts like this which require validation methods makes things very hard on yourself.

If you change the signature of the method so that it takes a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) rather than a `string`, you make life simpler - as it *has* to be a valid `Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Pure]
    public static bool IsUri(this string str)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(!Contract.Result<bool>() || str != null); // by Dan Bryant
        var result = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(str, UriKind.Absolute);
        Contract.Assume(!result || str != null); 
        return result;
    }
```